# DAX: Weighted Average on Different Level of Aggregation using Netted Summarized Table

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, summarize, weighted-average

I have the following test Data set, with 3 different levels of grouping. And I want to make a measure "Value WA" for Value, and the make a matrix like showing in the image after. Basically, it is the weighted average of "Value" based on "Market Value“ for the sub-categories contained in it. If it is on row of "Portfolio1", it is the WA of Index1 and Index2, and if it is on row of "Class1", it is the WA of "Portfolio1" and "Portfolio2" etc.

I had the code for measure "Value WA" at the bottom using netted SUMMARIZE. But somehow it doesn't work appropriately.  I can't figure out why, but I guess it is on the last line of "RETURN SUMX(SubTable2, [Value2] * [WT2])"

Please help me with the correct approach. Thank you very much!

[Date set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz2xc.png)

| GroupLevel1 | GroupLevel2 | GroupLevel3 | Market Value | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class1 | Portfolio1 | Index1 | 30 | 3 |
| Class1 | Portfolio1 | Index2 | 30 | 2 |
| Class1 | Portfolio1 | Index8 | 30 | 4 |
| Class1 | Portfolio2 | Index3 | 50 | 4 |
| Class2 | Portfolio3 | Index4 | 50 | 6 |
| Class2 | Portfolio4 | Index5 | 50 | 4 |
| Class3 | Portfolio5 | Index6 | 200 | 5 |
| Class3 | Portfolio5 | Index7 | 200 | 1 |

[what I want it to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8O0J.jpg)

```html
Value WA = 
IF( ISFILTERED('Table'[GroupLevel3]),
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value])),
    VAR SubTable1 = 
            ADDCOLUMNS(
                SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[GroupLevel3],'Table'[GroupLevel2],'Table'[GroupLevel1]),
                "WT3", CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Market Value])) /
                       CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Market Value]),
                                ALL('Table'[GroupLevel3])),
                "Value3", CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value])))
    VAR Val_level2 = SUMX(SubTable1, [Value3] * [WT3])
    RETURN
        IF( ISFILTERED('Table'[GroupLevel2]),
            Val_level2,
            VAR SubTable2 = ADDCOLUMNS(
                                SUMMARIZE(SubTable1,[GroupLevel2]),
                                "WT2", CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Market Value])) /
                                       CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Market Value]),
                                                ALL('Table'[GroupLevel2])),
                                "Value2", Val_level2)
            RETURN SUMX(SubTable2, [Value2] * [WT2])
    )
)
```

Comment: The Market Value entries in your two linked pictures do not seem to match. Can you correct and/or clarify?